# How to export array from inside addEventListener to another JS file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, web-applications

My web app has a filter page, where if the value of the last filter is set, the addEventListener creates an array using `filter()`, from my dataset array , `filterArr`, based on the values chosen in the select elements.

**How do I export the resulting array to another JS file?**

Using `export default arrForQuiz` generates the error "unexpected token: export".

Have added the code for the addEventListener and a visual of what I am trying for. Besides that, both JS files involved have `type="module"` and, as in picture, the original dataset array is already imported from a third file.

I am quite new to this. Was getting all kinds of strange errors when I used one JS file (for two pages), so switched to this approach which so far works well. If it's not a great idea, I'm all ears.

Code:

```
chooseSection.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let arrForQuiz = filterArr.filter( function(el) {
        return  el.book === chooseBook.value &&
                el.chapter === chooseChapter.value &&
                el.section === chooseSection.value;
        }); 
    // export arrForQuiz to another file
});
```

Visual:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless tries of different things, this is what worked. Thanks to Andre for the inspiration. His answer should probably work, I think I just wasn't doing it right.

Solution:
Pass the selected values to the other js file with sessionStorage and do the filtering there.

Code in filter.js:
-> as the value of the last select element changes, store all the selected values in sessionStorage.

```
chooseSection.addEventListener("input", () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('storedBook', chooseBook.value);
    sessionStorage.setItem('storedChapter', chooseChapter.value);
    sessionStorage.setItem('storedSection', chooseSection.value);
});
```

Code in script.js:
-> get the selected values from sessionStorage and use them to filter the data array.

```
let selectedBook = sessionStorage.getItem('storedBook');
let selectedChapter = sessionStorage.getItem('storedChapter');
let selectedSection = sessionStorage.getItem('storedSection');

let quizArr = mainArr.filter( function(el) {
    return  el.book === selectedBook &&
            el.chapter === selectedChapter &&
            el.section === selectedSection;
});
```

Visual:

[image: Visual of solution]

Answer (score 1):

I would define `arrForQuiz` as an export and import it in the files I want to share it. This way changes made in one file will be visible in the other.

For example, like so:

`shared-stuff.js`

```
export const sharedObject = [];
```

`file-a.js`

```
import { sharedObject } from './shared-stuff.js';

// moving the pointer will push a `1` into the shared array
window.addEventListener('pointermove', () => sharedObject.push(1);
```

`file-b.js`

```
import { sharedObject } from './shared-stuff.js';

// clicking the window will output the shared arrays current content
window.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(sharedObject));
```

For this to work, the exported value needs to be an object and can't be reassigned in one of the files using it. Otherwise there won't be a common binding to the shared memory.

In your example, the filtering would need to preserve the original array, so you would have to re-write the filtering. Instead of `arrForQuiz = filterArr.filter(...)` you would do something like this:

```
// we iterate over the array in reverse order, as we might change the input array
// and we don't want to mess up the indexing
for (let i = arrForQuiz.length - 1; i < 0; i -= 1) {
    const el = arrForQuiz[i];

    if (el.book === chooseBook.value &&
        el.chapter === chooseChapter.value &&
        el.section === chooseSection.value) {
        continue;
    }
    
    // Array.prototype.splice changes the array in place
    arrForQuiz.splice(i, 1);
}
```

You could stick with a more functional approach to dealing with the array, when exporting an object, which has a field, that holds the array. Here's a little more detail on what I mean by that:

`shared-stuff-2.js`

```
export const state = { sharedArray: [] };
```

If you define your export like this, changes to the `state` obejct are shared between imports again, but with the twist, that you can normally assign to fields, like in our case `sharedArray`, and those changes will propagate to other files importing the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Great idea to define the object in a shared-stuff.js. However I get an error when I try to reassign the value. I don't understand what you mean by 'the exported value needs to be an object and can't be reassigned...' I need to do the reassigning, right? The shared object is empty when I create it in the shared-stuff.js and the purpose of my filter is to assign the correct values so that my next page can use those to run a quiz.

Comment: The value you want to share between files "needs to be an object" means, it should be a value that is passed around "by reference", like ``{}` or  `[]`. You can mutate the shared value (for example by using `splice` instead of `filter`), but you can't use `=` to re-assign it. To be able to do that you could export an object that has the value you want to share as a field. I'LL update my answer to give you a better idea of what I mean by that.

Comment: @bassiee I added some more detail to my answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for sticking with me. Can't get it to work unfortunately, it must be something else in my code somewhere. Thanks for the learning, any in case :)

The furthest I got was using using localStorage which got me to at least transfer the string length between files. Perhaps I can figure out how to access what's in the string somehow (even if it's only the index numbers of the data points I need in my original array, that would work).